What's more common: car seat or child seat?
What's more common for a safety seat for a child in a car: a car seat or a child seat? I've seen both but I feel that a car seat without an additional context can be misunderstood because it can be any seat in the car.

As you say, "car seat" without any further context would usually mean any adult-sized seat in a car.

@KillingTime makes sense, however, I've seen "car seat" on the Uber website and in the Lyft app in the meaning of child car seat. That confused me.

There are confounding variables for both "car seat" (could refer to an adult's car seat or to a child's car seat) and "child seat" (could refer to a child-size seat in a car or elsewhere, such as for a normal dining table chair or a shopping cart). Nevertheless the Ngram results for "car seat" vs. "carseat" vs. "child seat" vs. "childseat" are not close, and the linked matches for each term seem largely to be legitimate ones (not false positives).

Car seat.
The way we, at least in the US, commonly refer to this kind of safety device is "car seat".  Here are some examples:

We test and rate 100+ car seats so that we can make clear recommendations—and you can easily find the right fit.

Consumer Reports - Car Seats
Notice on that page that they do use "child seat" one time, but "car seat" somewhere around 12 times (depending on how you count duplicates).

Car seat and booster seat recommendations
Learn how to stay safe on the road. Follow these recommendations to ensure the safety of your child’s car seat.
Keep your child in their current car seat for as long as possible to maximize safety. That means following the car seat manufacturer's height and weight requirements.

King County - Car Seats, Booster Seats, and Seatbelts

A car seat is one of the most important gear purchases you're going to make as a new parent

Parents - How to Choose the Right Car Seat for Your Child
Although "car seat" sounds like it could be ambiguous enough to cause confusion, the fact is there's little reason to discuss the seats that are normally installed in a car, at least in comparison to child restraint systems.
While it's possible to replace the seats that are installed in a car, few people do so.  So if you're shopping for "car seats" and you're not looking at a specialty car parts catalog, the assumption would be that you need a car seat for a child.
If you order an Uber, or a rental car, it's taken for granted that the car will have normal seats. Thus if there's an option to "include car seat", there's no chance they'd be asking if you want normal seats in the car, and they must be asking about child car seats.
There are probably some contexts where the meaning could be ambiguous, for example, "My nephew threw up all over the car seat"1 (is my nephew a breast-fed baby, or a drunken 17-year-old?), but that's no reason to avoid the term.


I don't know if this is just my personal idiolect, but if someone threw up on the non-child seats in my car, I wouldn't say "threw up on my car seat", I'd say, "threw up in the car" or "threw up on the seat of the car".


Thank you for such an informative comment. I wonder if this is the same in the UK. On the gov.uk I've seen the term "child car seat" more often than "car seat". However, both terms are common in the media

@MaryZi "child car seat" is unambiguous without the need for context. "Car seat" makes sense in the context of children, and "child seat" in the context of cars

I've never heard 'car seat' used for 'child seat' in the UK.
